# Pandas DataFrame count occurrences for each element after each appearance in column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe like this one

```py
pd.DataFrame(data={"codes": [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,2]})

time    codes
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       0
5       1
6       1
7       0
8       0
9       1
10      2
11      2
```

I would like to count how many times each element in `codes` occur after each new appearance. Note that I do not want to compute `.value_counts()` for each element. For example, for `codes` value `1` it appears 3 times, value `0` appears 2 times, and value `2` appears 1 time. The analogy of the task would be to count user sessions.

Expected output:

```py
codes   count_occurences
1       3
0       2
2       1
```

Comment: I don't understand the value 2, to me it appears 2 times

Comment: As I said, I don't want the `value_counts` per se, but rather how many times the element appears after each element change. The goal logic would be anywhere between the lines of doing a shift and check `previous_code != current_code` and sum +1 each time it happens, per each code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pandas you could do something like

```
df.codes.loc[df.codes!=df.codes.shift()].value_counts()
```

This will count values in codes only where the element is not equal to the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this can be achieved in plain Python.

```
myList = [1,2,6,2,2,4,3,3,4,4,6,1,1,2,3]
listSet = set(myList)
count = {}

for k in listSet:
    count[k]=0

for k in range(0, len(myList)-1):
    if myList[k]!=myList[k+1]:
        count[myList[k]]+=1
count[myList[k+1]]+=1
print(count)
```

This gives:

```
{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 6: 2}
```

Comment: In that case it does not work as `3` appears 2 times. However it works for all the other ones. Perhaps there should be extra logic for handling the last element?

Comment: Nice solution, but is there merit to doing it in *pure* python? I mean pandas has so many nice convenience functions why not use those? -- I really don't mean to be disrespectful but this reminds me of the Fortran days and is a lot less readable than @gereleth solution.

Comment: @Magellan88 there sure are. Pandas is great and I am currently learning it for Data Science pre-requisite but OP didn't strictly asked for Pandas way. Just an idea.

Comment: That is an actual solution, which works fine. However, I cannot give you the solution reward for the question as I prefer @gereleth because he's implemented it in pandas way. Thank you for your answer, though!